# How to get an authorized user in firebase v9 on javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an observer who checks whether the user has logged in, if SO, writes it to the AuthUser variable.

But the variable lives only in the observer

```
export let authUser = "";

 const user = auth.currentUser;
function WatchToUser() {
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
     authUser = user.email;
    } else {
   }
  });
```

Later I want to check this user on another page, if he is authorized, then show him the database, if not, then send it to the home page. But on another page, the variable is already an empty string.

It turns out that when switching to another html page, the user disappears, what to do?

```
showUsers.addEventListener("click", () => {
if (authUser != null && authUser != "") {
  window.location.replace("users.html");
} else {
  modalVisible("Need to login", isError());
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function that returns a `Promise` once Auth state is loaded like this:

```
function getUser() {
  return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
    const unsub = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      unsub(); 
      return resolve(user) // or throw error is user is not logged in
    })
  })
}

// await getUser()
```

However, it seems you are calling a function when a button is click. So the auth state could be loaded already so you could just use `currentUser` (assuming the page is shown to user only if they are authenticated).

```
showUsers.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const user = auth.currentUser;
  
  if (user) {
    window.location.replace("users.html");
  } else {
    modalVisible("Need to login", isError());
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't quite understand how I can use promise in my code

Comment: @Wyse instead of `watchToUser`, you'll call `getUser` in the on click listener. `const user = await getUser()` and then run same logic

Comment: I've been trying to do this task all my one day off. But I have achieved the necessary logic thanks to you. 

Show my result later c:

Comment: @Wyse what is not working? Have you tried the code in my answer?

Comment: Everything is working, there are still some tasks on this form. I'll post the finished pet project later

Comment: I did https://iwyse.github.io/LoginForm/

The last thing I want to fix

When the mobile screen is small in height, the alert is ALWAYS shown at the top of the page itself, and not the window of the mobile device

Comment: @Wyse sounds like a UI related question. Can you share your HTML/CSS and explain the issue in a new question? That might help getting more attention from CSS devs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73684732/how-to-display-an-alert-at-the-top-of-the-window-and-not-the-page