# How to display an alert at the top of the window and not the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If the registration is successful or the form is entered incorrectly, an alert appears
[image]

But if the mobile device is smaller than the entire page in height, then the alert is not visible, because it appears only at the top of the page

How to make it so that it always appears at the top of the user window?

modal.scss
[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing `position: absolute;` to `position: fixed;` of the modal?

Comment: Please create a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: thx https://iwyse.github.io/LoginForm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#modal{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thx https://iwyse.github.io/LoginForm/